# How do I wirelessly connect my iPad with iTunes?

Tags: ipad, itunes

I want to connect my iPad wirelessly with iTunes. Can it be done?

If it can be done, please explain on how it can be done.

Comment: Home sharing and the free remote app work well.

Comment: You can enable WiFi-synchronization and then the iPad will synchronize over WiFi when it is on the same network as iTunes and attached to power.

Answer (score 6):

- If you're looking for a way to stream music from iTunes to your iPad, you can use Home Sharing in the Music app:

  [image]
- If you're looking for a way to control iTunes from your iPad, you can use the [Remote app, available from the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8):

  [image]
- Finally, if you're looking for a way to wirelessly sync your iPad with iTunes, that is an [announced feature of the next version of iOS](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#more), due out in the fall.

  [image]

Comment: I hate how there are multiple apps that do similar things that look similar. apple needs to make one app where you can access all home sharing media and play it on any device.

Comment: But there is. You use the Music and the Video app that come pre-installed on your device and connect to your home-shared iTunes library. It's as easy as that.

If you then download bazillions of other Apps that have similar icons and do similar things it's not really Apple's fault, is it?

Answer (score 3):

To access your computer's music from your iPad, enable Home Sharing on both devices and use the Music app on the iPad to connect to iTunes.

To access your computer's videos from your iPad, enable Home Sharing and use the Movies app on the iPad to connect to iTunes.

To access your iPad's apps, files, music, movies, etc. (anything you can normally access via USB), follow these steps:

1. Enable Wi-Fi Sync in Settings > General on your iPad.
2. Connect your iPad to iTunes via USB and let it mount.
3. Remove the iPad's physical connection, and it'll stay in the Devices area of the iTunes sidebar.

To control iTunes with your iPad, follow these steps:

1. Download and use the Remote app from the App Store.
2. Tick "Allow iTunes audio control from remote speakers" in the Devices pane of iTunes's preferences.
3. Open the remote app, and follow the steps to connect the two outlined in the Remote app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but if you try going to settings and then disconnect then connect agin it should solve the problem.

Comment: Could you flesh this out with some more detail?

Answer (score -1):

One way to sync the iPad with iTunes now, without having to wait for iOS 5 is the jailbreak and then buy the Cydia app Wi-Fi Sync. More information is available here: http://wifisyncapp.com/beta/